# Problems with constraint FK defenition

Tags: sql, spring-boot, h2

My problem is that i am trying to config my h2 database and using some scripts for that. 
Application start fails on creating Tables.
Listing and stacktrace is below. It is for internal develope and this scripts are generated automatically with IDEA. I am bad with SQL, so i think that it could be child mistake. But somehow i have checked a lot of site, articles and etc. and still dont know, where am i wrong.

```
create table Table1
(
    record_ID int not null,
    dateTime datetime not null,
    timerName varchar(14) not null
        constraint Table1_Table2_timerName_fk
        references Table2(timerName)
            on update cascade,
    status smallint,
    primary key (record_ID, spotName, partIdentString)
);

create table Table2
(
    timerName varchar(14) not null
        constraint Table2_pk
        primary key nonclustered,
    center varchar(2),
    station varchar(4)  not null,
    cell varchar(6)  not null,
    place varchar(10) not null
);
```

Then i am trying to run app it fails with

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of file [****\target\classes\sql\schema\my_dbo_Table1.sql]: create table Table1 ( record_ID int not null, dateTime datetime not null, timerName varchar(14) not null constraint 
Table1_Table2_timerName_fk references Table2(timerName) on update cascade, status smallint, primary key (record_ID, spotName, partIdentString) ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "Table2" not found; SQL statement:
create table Table1 ( record_ID int not null, dateTime datetime not null, timerName varchar(14) not null constraint Table1_Table2_timerName_fk references Table2(timerName) on update cascade, status smallint, primary key (record_ID, spotName, partIdentString) ) [42102-197]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:493)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:238)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:192)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runSchemaScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.init(DataSourceInitializer.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "Table2" not found; SQL statement:
create table Table1 ( record_ID int not null, dateTime datetime not null, timerName varchar(14) not null constraint Table1_Table2_timerName_fk references Table2(timerName) on update cascade, status smallint, primary key (record_ID, spotName, partIdentString) ) [42102-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.tryUpdate(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:204)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.update(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:78)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CommandWithColumns.createConstraints(CommandWithColumns.java:88)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateTable.update(CreateTable.java:122)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:102)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:261)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:233)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:472)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

> nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "Table2" not found;

Table1, which you are trying to create first, has a constraint that reference to Table2.

To solve the errror, invert the CREATE TABLE commands in your script : you must  create Table2 first, then Table1.

NB : DateTime is a data type for sqlserver. You should avoid naming your columns like reserved words, this can cause a variety of surprising behaviors.